# Git Gui showing 8000 files from AppData

Tags: git, user-interface, repository

`Git Gui` is showing over 8000 files from the `.gem` and `AppData` directories which is preventing me from seeing my actual repository.

**How can I prevent git from seeing these files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .gitignore file. Place a file named .gitignore in the root of your checked out repository that includes the names of the files you want ignored. Wildcards are ok. Putting in a directory name will ignore everything in that directory.

Here's [an example from GitHub](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/).

In your case you'd want a file named `.gitignore` with the following:

```
.gem
AppData
```

Comment: I want to ignore the entire directories, I don't want it picking up anything in `appdata` or `.get`. Meaning I want to remove what's telling it to pick up those files rather than telling it to not pick up those files.

Comment: Putting the directory name in will ignore everything in that directory.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a repository on that drive at all, why was it picking up those files?

Comment: git gui is picking up files outside of the folder you cloned your repo into? Is this on Linux? maybe there's some symbolic links that git is following.

Comment: I have no idea, I uninstalled/reinstalled a bunch of times same thing, I'm on windows 7. I am trying to create a repo in `D:/wampserver/www/`  and it's not working at all.

Comment: If you have a git repo in D:/wampserver/www and you run git gui from there, you should only get files/folders within D:/wampserver/www . Just so I have a better picture of what's going on, did you install git through msysgit or cygwin?

Comment: My problem was the fact that I completely misunderstood the concept of Git Gui, I've got it now, thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just an FYI, the installer from git-scm.com is what I meant by msysgit.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .gitignore file and insert patterns for all files you want to exclude there,

```
.gem
AppData
```

should do the trick